# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline - Deploy Multiple ISPAC Files using SSIS Deploy Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssis, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are using **Azure DevOps Pipeline to Build & Deploy ISPAC files**. As of now we keep multiple ISPAC files in a single folder like "Development" has Staging.ISPAC, ETL.ISPAC, DataMart.ISPAC. To deploy these ISPAC using Azure Release Pipeline we need to create multiple [SSIS Deploy Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#ssis-deploy-task)
in release pipeline and deploy each. If there is addition of new ISPAC files everytime I need to modify Azure Release Pipeline.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#ssis-deploy-task) on SSIS Deploy Task mentions we can deploy single or multiple ISPAC files as quoted "*SSIS Deploy task supports deploying single or multiple ispac files to on-premises SSIS catalog and Azure-SSIS IR, or SSISDeploymentManifest files and their associated files to on-premises or Azure file share.*"

However there is no option available to configure SSISDB Path/ ISPAC files mapping if there are multiple ISPAC through any configurations. Could anyone suggest what could be a better approach to deploy multiple ISPAC files by making changes in configuration file to have mapping of ISPAC File & Target SSISDB Folder/Project Name and deploy through a single SSIS Deploy Task.